# Future of the with-statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dsl, coffeescript, ecmascript-5

I know that usage of the *with*-statement [is not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) in Javascript and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5, but it allows one to create some nice DSLs in Javascript.

For example [CoffeeKup](http://coffeekup.org/)-templating engine and the [Zappa](https://github.com/mauricemach/zappa) web DSL. Those uses some [very](https://github.com/mauricemach/coffeekup/blob/bd1199258221d21c432009bda9e5d35ee3daa010/lib/coffeekup.coffee#L143) [weird](https://github.com/mauricemach/zappa/blob/5ccf1cb77a6cf258d6093a8ee97132560834e5a5/lib/zappa.coffee#L417) scoping methods with the *with*-statement to achieve DSLish feeling to them.

Is there any future with the *with*-statement and these kinds of DSLs?

Can this DSL-effect be achieved without the *with*-statement?

Comment: ES Next quasi-literals look like they will become JS DSL tool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`with` being "forbidden" in ECMAScript 5 is a **common misconception**.

Only in strict mode of ECMAScript 5 — which is **opt-in**, mind you — `with` statement is a syntax error. So you can certainly still use `with` in fully ECMAScript 5 -compliant implementations, as long as they occur in non-strict (or sloppy, as Crockford calls it) code. It won't be pretty for performance (since mere presence of `with` often kills various optimizations in modern engines) but it will work.

Future versions of ECMAScript are very likely to be based on strict mode behavior, although will also likely be opt-in as well. So conforming to strict mode is certainly a good idea when it comes to future proofing your scripts.

Answer (score 10):

In coffeescript, there is a nice trick to keep using fancy dsls without using `with`:

```
 using = (ob, fn) -> fn.apply(ob)

 html = 
   head : (obj) -> # implementation
   body : (fn)  -> # implementation
   div  : (str) -> # implementation

 using html, ->
   @head
     title: "My title"
   @body =>
     @div "foo bar"
     @div "qux moo"

 /*
   in pure javascript you'd be using
   with(html){
     head({title:"My title"});
     body(function(){
       div("foo bar");
       div("qux moo");
     });
   }
 */
```

Comment: Ah, awesome! This is almost as clean as the with-trick. Anyone yet implemented a templating engine using this?

Comment: Don't think so, however it should be possible to adapt coffeekup (https://github.com/mauricemach/coffeekup) to that effect.

Comment: This is not the same as what "with" does. "with" puts variables directly in scope, not as properties of "this".

Answer (score 2):

Why not just assign a var to point to the object instead of using with?

'with' style:

```
with(a_long_object_name_that_is_bloated) {
  propertyA = 'moo';
  propertyB = 'cow';
}
```

'var' style:

```
var o = a_long_object_name_that_is_bloated;
o.propertyA = 'moo';
o.propertyB = 'cow';
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer Epeli's question, take a look at [CoffeeMugg](https://github.com/jaekwon/coffeemugg) which does what CoffeeKup does but using Adrien's technique. It uses `this.` instead of the `with` statement.