# Safe use of "with" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Pretty much every resource documenting `with` that I can find warns against using it, mostly because if a variable is not defined it may have unpredictable effects.

I want to understand it so that I can make effective use of it - after all, it's there for a reason. Even `eval` has its non-evil uses!

So, with that in mind, let's say I want to delete all child nodes from an element, without using `elem.innerHTML = "";`

Would the following be safe?

```
with(elem) while(firstChild) removeChild(firstChild);
```

Note that at this point I'm not caring for readability, just functionality. Since `firstChild` is a property of, and `removeChild` a method of, all element nodes, it should be fine to use `with` this way, right?

Similarly, let's say I want to set some styles.

```
with(elem.style) {
    color = "red";
    backgroundColor = "black";
    fontWeight = "bold";
}
```

Since all of these are properties of the style object (even if not defined in the stylesheet, they are there as empty strings), it's fine to use `with` like this, right?

Am I missing something, or is the constant warning to not use `with` similar to the one against PHP's `mysql` extension: a protection against dumb programmers?

Comment: I vote for a protection against misuse

Comment: Keep in mind that usage of the `with` statement throws an error in strict mode. So I'd say there might be more to it than just "protection" (but cannot say what right now and the spec is not specific in this point).

Comment: I think the main danger of `with` is that the variables are exposed to the whole scope, but I've seen workarounds with IIFEs. Apparently it's _very_ slow when you can just cache the lookup in a variable and use that right? But that danger can be an advantage I suppose.

Comment: `eval` has its non-evil useS? I can think of one, that doesn't apply anymore: eval-ing JSON strings, but thanks to `JSON.parse`, we don't have to.

Comment: Please search before asking: exact duplicate of [Are there legitimate uses for JavaScript's "with" statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement). Also related: [Future of the with-statement in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373577/future-of-the-with-statement-in-javascript)

Comment: The main argument against using `with` is the relative difficulty to reason about it.

Comment: @Bergi The more I read SO, the more I'm certain that *all good questions* are already asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `with` keyword in Javascript is a bit of a throwback to when it was competing with VBScript in the late 90s. It's still there, but disabled if you `'use strict';` and considered an error by just about every Javascript validator out there.

There are two major problems with it, both related to the way scope works in Javascript:

```
var color = "green";
var foo = "bar";

with(elem.style) {
    color = "red";
    foo = "something else";
}
```

What's `color` now? What is `foo`? Not only is this confusing code, but due to how Javascript looks up variables in the `with` scope it's also *very slow code* as now every statement has an additional scope to search for each variable used.

This is one of the reasons why modern frameworks like jQuery and Prototype use chaining. They use `call` and `apply` on functions to control what `this` represents, meaning that you make calls to `this.something` rather than `with(this){something}`.

So to answer your question: there is one good use of `with` in Javascript - allowing IE4 and IE5 websites written in the 90s to still work today.

That's it. You shouldn't use it in new code.

Answer (score 1):

The only safe use of `with` is not using it at all. There's no task that can't be accomplished without it and modern standards outright disable it in strict mode.

For all purposes it is considered a design mistake that is only preserved for backwards compatibility.

Comment: How would you accomplish to write a templating engine [like this](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-135) without `with` and similar simplicity?

Comment: @Bergi - The Underscore template engine does not require `with`. Search the code and docs for `settings.variable`. It only uses `with` if you don't provide a `settings.variable`.

Comment: Yes I know that, but with a variable the template source needs to use dot accessors over and over. If they shell be avoided, you can use `with` (and it's fine there).

Answer (score 0):

`with` simply puts the variable on top of the stack of "maps" searched for variables.

Normal stack is  (searched top to bottom)

- window
- (root - just having `window`)

So if you have

```
var foo = { document: "doc.pdf" };
window.myFunc = function(){
    with( foo ){
        alert( document );
    }
}
```

The stack within `with` is

- foo
- window
- (root - just having `window`)

It will surely print `foo.document` and not `window.document`.

In this case it's obvious that you shouldn't use `document` like that, as it's typically used in browsers. But ECMAScript specification doesn't define that, so in other environments, other variables may be on the stack by default (even more of them).

The danger is that whatever you call within the `with` statement has that on the stack too.
This would fail on the `document.url` call:

```
// Some 3rd-party library
function redirect( url ){
    document.url = url;    // url is undefined in document
}

var bar = { document: "20x20" };

with( bar ){
    redirect(); //
}
```

Comment: The actual danger is described here: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/

Comment: What's the difference between `root` and `window`? And your "danger" example is completely wrong; have you tried it?

Comment: That's the same case. And the example is from a book by David Flanagan.

Comment: If `window` *is* your `root` scope, don't put them on different bullet points to avoid confusion :-) Oh, and throw that book away. Test the code *yourself*.

Comment: No, it's not root scope. Root scope is the scope which has `window`. Then comes `window`. See e.g. the source code of Firefox.

Comment: Don't forget that JavaScript is not only in browsers. It's also e.g. in Thunderbird, Adobe products, etc. And `window` is not the main variable there. The root context contains other objects.

Comment: Well, `window` is just a variable in the root scope that points to the root scope itself, isn't it?

Comment: Not really, try `window.window.window`

Comment: Ha! That didn't work years ago :) You got me. Perhaps they changed that to be compatible with IE which did that.

Answer (score 0):

The `with` statement is just a shorthand for writing recurring accesses to objects:

For

```
foobar.foo.bar.baz = 'bubu';
foobar.foo.bar.buz = 'baba';
```

you can write

```
with(foobar.foo.bar){
    baz = 'bubu';
    buz = 'baba';
}
```

Thats nice! BUT will foobar.foo.bar be modified or will the global variables baz and buz modified?
In some cases it is impossible to know for sure.

JavaScript provides a better alternative

```
var better = foobar.foo.bar;
better.baz = 'bubu';
better.buz = 'baba';
```

Now there is no ambiguity.