# Is it possible to import variables in JavaScript (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have variables in **`app.js`**:

```
var G = {};
module.exports = G;

var DATA = G.DATA = 'DATA';
var F1 = G.F1　= function(val)
{
  return val;
};
```

In this manner, I can export variables under the object `G`, and at the same time, can access the variable directly writing `DATA` without `G.` prefix.

So far so good.

Now, I want to run a *test* for `app.js` in **`test.js`**:

```
var G = require('./app.js');
console.log(G.DATA);  // -> DATA
```

This works, but I also want to access the variable directly writing `DATA` without `G.` prefix like `console.log(DATA);  // -> DATA`

Surely, I could do like

`var DATA = G.DATA;` for every variables(property) export&required module `G` object, but obviously it's a tedious process to add every variable to the test file manually to correspond the `G` objects.

Is there any way to do this automatically?

So far, I'm pessmistic since

JS `function` encloses `var` in the own scope, so in theory there's no way to have a helper function to `var` for every object property.

Thanks.

PS. I would like to avoid any `eval` or `VM` of node solution. I have tried them in past, and too much problems.

Comment: That's generally a bad idea.

Comment: Please explain why you want to access those variables directly, so we can suggest a better approach.

Comment: Ok, my project is basically a interpreter on top of JS, like `coffee-script`, and I want to have a variable `DATA` as `DATA` not `G.DATA` in the testing process. So far I have a test code in the same `app.js` file, but if possible I want to export the variables in a Object (in this case `G`) to a separate file - `test.js`.

Comment: There are no variables in an object, only properties, which are quite different things. Still you could do `for (k in G) { console.log(k,G[k]); }` in your test.js (if your test is to display the values of the properties of G).

Comment: Thank you. `for in` sounds a good way to obtain properties, however, as I mentioned earlier, I would like to have a variables having a corresponding name for each property .

Comment: Bad idea, but good question :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I could assign a local variables for every property export&required module G object, but obviously it's a tedious process to add every variable to the test file manually to correspond the G objects.

No, that's how it is supposed to work. You - and only you - are in charge of what local variables exist in your module scope. No changes in the "export variables" of an included module should break your code.

Accessing properties on the imported module (with a self-chosen name) is the way to go. This is quite equivalent to Python's `import app` or `import app as g`.

If you want some particular properties as local variables, you will usually choose them manually, as in Python's `from app import DATA, F1`. In JS, you will need a [multiple `var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) like the one you've shown in your question. However, there is a syntax feature called [destructuring assignment](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adestructuring) which will make this more fluid. You can use this in [JavaScript 1.7+ (Gecko)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7), [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring), or [EcmaScript 6](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/50/):

```
var {DATA, F1} = require("app.js");
```

> Is there any way to do this automatically?

Yes and No. You *should not* do this, but you can - just like Python's frowned-upon `from app import *`. To cite [what they say](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules), which is equally true for JavaScript:

> [It] introduces an unknown set of names into the interpreter, possibly
>   hiding some things you have already defined.
>
> Note that in general the practice of importing `*` from a module or
>   package is frowned upon, since it often causes poorly readable code.
>   However, it is okay to use it to save typing in interactive sessions.

In JavaScript, you can<sup>[1]</sup> [use the `with`-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement):

```
with (require("app.js")) {
    …
}
```

<sub>[1]: [Not in ES5.1 *strict mode*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373577/future-of-the-with-statement-in-javascript), though - which is recommended for optimisation</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your detailed instruction.