# Add variable to a functions scope / closure. function equivalent of window object

Tags: javascript, function, scope, closures

With the following code I am able to take values out of an object and add them to the global namespace. This is defined in the expose function

```
function expose(key, obj){
  window[key] = obj[key];
}
```

I can have been using it to take functions I use a lot out of libraries, such as map from underscore

```
// before
map               //undefined
_.map             // have to use like this

expose('map', _)

// after
map // function
```

I would like modify expose so that it does the same job but only in a closure. How to solve this is the question I am trying to articulate.

```
map //undefined

(function(){
expose('map', {})

// map can be used here 
}())
// map is still undefined here.
```

I know this problem in this case can be solved with a `var map = _.map` I am presenting a simplified version to describe the point here. I would like to solve it as described above to I can write a function that exposes more than one variable at a time.

For an complex example have a look at this repo.

https://github.com/CrowdHailer/cuminjs

The tests for the expose function are found here

https://github.com/CrowdHailer/cuminjs/blob/master/spec/cumin_spec.js

Large example to express better what I want the end result to be

```
// file one - sets up some core utilities
var MyModule = (function(){
var foo = function(){
  // ..some functionality
};

return {
  foo: foo
  // plus several more functions
};
}());


// file two - sets up some other functionality.
// Makes use of lots of the functions set up in file 1
(function(parent){
  // var foo = MyModule.foo -trying to avoid as want to use several maybe names change

  expose([foo, etc], MyModule);

  var bar = function(){
    // .. other code would like to make use of foo
  };

  parent.extend({
    bar: bar
  });
}(MyModule))
```

Comment: just curious are you trying to do something similar to RequireJS (http://requirejs.org/)?

Comment: I have not got much experience with requirejs at all. However a quick read over seams that it could be a similar thing. Does require allow you to require items into a closure?

Comment: Well its more of a module loader. But yes it allows you to define modules (as closures) and then "require" them as dependencies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Is creating a custom object, and assigning external library methods as methods of that object acceptable?  (for example use my.map(thing) instead of map(thing) inside your closure)  If not I don't see a way of doing it without using eval.

Answer (score 0):

> I know this problem in this case can be solved with a `var map = _.map`.

That's exactly the (only) way to go.

> I want write a function that exposes more than one variable at a time.

You should not. Have a look at my answer on the dual question [Is it possible to import variables in JavaScript (node.js)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21562973/1048572)

However, `export`ing variables (into a scope that you don't own) is even more complicated than `import`ing (into your own scope). Basically, it is impossible because scopes (apart from `global`) are not objects that can be passed around, and be dynamically modified.

> How to solve this

You need to modify the code of the function whose scope you want to change/extend. I can think of two ways:

- use `eval`. `export()` will return a statement that will declare and initialise the variables:

  ```
  function export() {
      var lines = [];
      for (var p in moduletoexpose)
          lines.push("var "+p+" = require('moduletoexpose')."+p+";");
      return lines.join("\n");
  }

  (function() {
      eval(export(…));
      // use `map` here
  }())
  ```
- Similarly, you could write a function that takes the closure, decompiles it, adds the variable declarations to the code, and uses the `Function` constructor to create a function from it. It might be used like

  ```
  exportTo(…, function() {
      // use `map` here
      // don't use any free variables but global ones
  })();
  ```

  Doesn't sound as good as the `eval` solution, but you might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24032179/1048572) for inspiration on how to write such an `exportTo`.

Comment: This looks like it has what I am looking for. I had heard that eval was something to avoid. I will try and write a better example of what I am trying to achieve with breaking up closures to create large pieces of functionality with pollute global namespace only once.

Comment: Yes, `eval` is to avoid, but it's the only way to achieve what you want. You might of course want to avoid `export()`ing at all as I suggested (see the link about importing variables).