# Compelling ECMAScript 6 Destructuring use cases

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, destructuring

Why was destructuring introduced to ECMAScript 6?

Comment: There seem to be two different questions here. Are you looking for "compelling use cases" or an explanation/justification for the example code?

Comment: Compelling use cases

Comment: @SamLeach You might want to check [these examples](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:destructuring#examples) out

Comment: I have edited the question to be a specific question.

Comment: It's still not a very good question for SO. To get information about *why* a certain feature was added to a language or why it works that way, you have better chances getting an answer from the people working on the language. E.g. https://esdiscuss.org/

Answer (score 4):

Trivial example:

```
var {forEach} = Array.prototype;
forEach.call(document.querySelector(...
```

Argument destructuring is fun:

```
function ({opt1 = true, opt2 = false, opt3} = {}) { ...
```

Comment: There are default values in the destructuring syntax?

Comment: Wow, I didn't knew that. +1!

Comment: Yes, this works not only in argument lists, but in general: `var { x = 3 } = {};`.

Comment: Here's your useless destructuring brain-teaser of the day: what does `var {x} = 1;` do? TypeError? Or...?

Comment: @torazaburo `undefined` most likely. `typeof (1).x == "undefined"`

Answer (score 4):

Here is another one: [**`Map#entries`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) returns an iterator over `(key, value)` tuples. The most elegant way to iterate over them is use destructuring:

```
for (var [key, value] of map.entries()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1, that's the one that came to my mind after I had posted my list :-)

Answer (score 2):

> not sure why I would want to use `[x, y] = [y, x]`.

Because using an extra variable two swap two values is cumbersome, and JS with its pass-by-value function calls does not let you write a  `swap` function.

> most compelling use cases for ECMAScript 6's destructuring feature?

What I can think of, this mostly will be used for

- multiple function return values

  ```
  function rgb2hsv(r, g, b) {
       …
       return {h, s, v};
  }
  …
  var {h, s, v} = rgb2hsv(…);
  ```

  ```
  Promise.spawn(function* () {
      …
      var [a, b] = yield [async1(), async2()];
      …
  })
  ```
- [importing modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21562973/1048572), e.g. something like

  ```
  var {abs, trunc, round} = require('Math')
  ```