# Avoiding repetition in destructuring argument

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a function `ValidateInteger`, that returns an object which looks something like:

```
{
    Value: "123",
    Neg: false,
    Exp: 3
}
```

I also have a class which calls this function:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(val) {
        {
          Value: this.Value
          Neg: this.Neg
          Exp: this.Exp
        } = ValidateInteger(val);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's quite a bit repetition with the `this`.

My question is there some better syntax to do this, something like:

```
this.{Value, Neg, Exp} = ValidateInteger(val);
```

There surely should be some better syntax for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). It can be used to copy the values of enumerable properties from some objects to another one.

```
Object.assign(this, ValidateInteger(val));
```

```js
var ValidateInteger = val => ({
  Value: "123",
  Neg: false,
  Exp: 3
});
class MyClass {
  constructor(val) {
    Object.assign(this, ValidateInteger(val));
  }
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(
  new MyClass() // MyClass { Value: "123", Neg: false, Exp: 3 }
, null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: The problem is that this will release *all* variables which I won't always want. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31908049/1620622) answer is also recommending to avoid using Object.assign to release an object to a scope.

Comment: @Downgoat Bergi recommends not assigning random properties **to the global object**, and I completely agree. Here I am using `Object.assign` to assign properties to an instance.

Comment: @Downgoat I don't know what you mean by "release all variables". It will assign all the properties in the object returned from `ValidateInteger` to `this`. This would be a problem only if the object returned from `ValidateInteger` included other properties which you do not want to assign to `this`; if that is the case, you will simply have to list them out. I also can't understand what you mean by "release an object to a scope". That answer is about something else entirely; it refers to defining **local variables** for all properties in an object.