# destructuring base on dynamic value es6

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I have an express endpoint, I need to get the query pass from the frontend

`const { filterType1, filterType2 } = req.query`

the problem is the filterType is from elsewhere, says it's list of array

`const list = ['priceFilter', 'ageFilter', 'destinationFilter']`

can I do this?

`const { list.map(o => o) } = req.query` which means

`const { priceFilter , ageFilter, destinationFilter } = req.query`

Comment: No, it's impossible, because that would require dynamic variable names.

Comment: Probably a duplicate (but I won't close yours for now): https://stackoverflow.com/q/35939289/5768908

Comment: @CertainPerformance if it's not possible how should I solve above problem? you have a list that's coming from elsewhere, you want to pass in in req.query.somethingdynamic here. Do I have to hard code it, next time the list got updated I have to manually modify the query param?

Comment: Simple, just don't destructure - instead, just iterate through the `list` array (or the `Object.entries` of the `req.query`)

Comment: @Hanz: The problem is already solved. Just don't destructure

Comment: it's not solved, where does it been solved?

Comment: how do you want to use these variables?

Comment: @AZ_ whatever object in the req.query

Answer (score 0):

You can filter request's query parameters according to the `filterTypes` array and then access the `filters` by iterating.

```js
function getFilters(req, filterTypes) {
  return Object.keys(req.query).reduce((acc, k) => {
    const isAllowedFilter = filterTypes.some(type => type === k);
    if (isAllowedFilter) {
      return { ...acc, [k]: req.query[k] };
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const filterTypes = ['priceFilter', 'ageFilter', 'destinationFilter'];

const req = {
  query: {
    priceFilter: '50-100',
    ageFilter: '8-20',
    destinationFilter: 'foo',
    unknownFilter: 'unknown',
  },
};

const filters = getFilters(req, filterTypes);

Object.keys(filters).forEach(k => console.log(`${k} -> ${filters[k]}`));
```

Comment: I don't want to get the filters, I want to pass it.