# Remove a dynamic property in the reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to dynamically pass the id of the entry I want to remove with the payload into the reducer and I am trying to delete an object property (the one with the "eowvw698x" id which is dynamical and may change) and preserve the existing ones.

```
case DELETE_ENTRY:
   return {
     ...state,
     diaryEntries: {
       ...state.diaryEntries,
       ??????
     },
   };
```

[image]

How can I achieve this?

## Edit

I've used Vencovsky's answer and Klaycon's comment suggestion and wrote:

```
case DELETE_ENTRY:
  const { [payload]: dontcare, ...otherProperties } = state.diaryEntries;
  return {
    ...state,
    diaryEntries: {
      ...otherProperties,
    },
  };
```

The solutions of other people mutated the state object, which is forbidden by the Supreme Algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could destruct `state.diaryEntries` to remove that id

```
   const { eowvw698x, ...otherProperties } = state.diaryEntries

   return {
     ...state,
     diaryEntries: {
       ...otherProperties 
     },
   };
```

OR

This isn't the best way, but you can set it to `undefined`.

```
   return {
     ...state,
     diaryEntries: {
       ...state.diaryEntries,
       eowvw698x: undefined 
     },
   };
```

## Edit

As said in the comments, what you are looking for is dynamically destruct a variable and you can see how to do this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939289/how-to-destructure-into-dynamically-named-variables-in-es6).

But for your example, what you can do is destruct and name the variable, only to remove it.

```
   const { [keyToRemove]: anyVariableNameYouWontUse, ...otherProperties } = state.diaryEntries

   return {
     ...state,
     diaryEntries: {
       ...otherProperties 
     },
   };
```

Comment: My component cannot read undefined from that property because it's still there, this results into a TypeError. I want it removed.

Comment: @MihaiCiobanu then use the first way this answer provides, which is destructuring.

Comment: @EmileBergeron To that edit: This whole thing happens in the reducer, I do not have any state object I can use. It's a case in a switch statement in the reducer.

Comment: @MihaiCiobanu it doesn't matter? You're already using `state.diaryEntries` in your question.

Comment: Don't you need `...` before `rest` in the destructure?

Comment: @Vencovsky When destructuring, the id that comes along with the action type into the reducer, is set dynamically, so I won't be able to destructure dynamically a prop like ```{ [payload], ...otherProperties } = state.diaryEntries```

Comment: @MihaiCiobanu please update your question accordingly, that's an important detail.

Comment: @MihaiCiobanu That can be done by aliasing: `{ [payload]: dontcare, ...otherProperties } = state.diaryEntries` will store the property whose key is the value of `payload` into `dontcare` and the rest of the properties in `otherProperties`

Comment: @MihaiCiobanu I think now is what you are looking for. Please be more clear on what you want next time, it wasn't clear that `eowvw698x` was a dynamic key and not hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

Just `delete` the property afterwards and be done with it:

```
case DELETE_ENTRY:
   let output = {
     ...state,
     diaryEntries: {
       ...state.diaryEntries
     },
   };
   delete output.diaryEntries[payload];
   return output;
```

Comment: This mutates the current state which is forbidden (with react or redux).

Comment: @EmileBergeron Understood, didn't know that. I've updated the answer.