# Javascript object destructure with property name in variable

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Is it possible to destructure an object in Javascript by using a property name stored in a variable?

This is how we destructure at the moment.

```
const myObject = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
let {a, b, c} = myObject;
console.log(a, b, c);
```

I would like to be able to store property names in variables:

```
const myObject = {banana: 1, apple: 2, strawberry: 3};
const chosenFruit = "banana";
const { [[chosenFruit]], ...theRest } = myObject;
console.log(banana); // Should be 1
```

For full disclosure, the reason I want to be able to do this is I want to remove the property "banana" from the object. So in my use case I want to be left with the `theRest` object which doesn't include the `banana` property, but there have been times I wanted to iterate through an array of values (e.g. days of the week) and programatically destructure objects quickly.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: `delete myObject.banana;` <= done

Comment: @Taplar you mean `delete myObject[choosenFruit]`

Comment: You did say your goal was to remove banana from the object.

Comment: Are you after something like `const { [chosenFruit]: banana, ...theRest } = myObject;` ? you would have to explicitly type `banana` in the destructuring though

Comment: `delete` will change the original object. I want the original object in tact, and I want a new object with the `banana` property missing.

Comment: So you could clone it and then remove it

Comment: See: [How to destructure into dynamically named variables in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35939289)

Comment: Yes, true, I could indeed. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could take a [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and rename the property ([assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)).

```js
const myObject = { banana: 1, apple: 2, strawberry: 3 };
const chosenFruit = "banana";
const { [chosenFruit]: fruit, ...theRest } = myObject;

console.log(fruit); // 1
console.log(theRest);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myObject = {banana: 1, apple: 2, strawberry: 3};
const chosenFruit = "banana";
const newThing = { ...myObject };

delete newThing[chosenFruit];

console.log(myObject, newThing);
```

This version uses deconstruction to clone, and then removes the unwanted property.

Comment: A good solution! Achieves the desired outcome with deleting the property, but doesn't translate to "normal" destructuring, unlike Nina's answer. :)

Comment: "normal" deconstruction?

Comment: Where you just want to pull values out of objects, rather than deleting them.

Comment: Ah, I gotcha.  True.

Comment: This doesnt have any destructuring

Comment: @AmaarshallYaswankar what would you call the `{ ...myObject }` then?

Comment: I would argue that the usage of the spread operator is a form of deconstructing.

Comment: Its ok my friend, iam not here to argue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224739/discussion-between-amaarshall-yaswankar-and-taplar).

Answer (score 0):

A variation with destructuring parameters:

```js
const pick = (fruit, {[fruit]: out, ...fruits}) => [out, fruits];

const [fruit, fruits] = pick('banana', basket);

console.log(fruit);
console.log(fruits);
console.log(basket);
```

```html
<script>const basket = { banana: 1, apple: 2, strawberry: 3 };</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works for non-dynamic choices and also if you want to have the variable name same as the fruit name

```
const myObject = { banana: 1, apple: 2, strawberry: 3 };
const { banana, ...theRest } = myObject;

console.log(banana); // 1
console.log(theRest);
```