# Javascript convert Object.keys to destructuring vars of other object

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to convert Object.keys to vars can be destructured for other object ?

So if I have

```
let ob1 = { key1: 'value', key2: 'value2'}
let dictionary = { key1: 'super value', key2: 'other value' }
```

can do this

```
let { Object.keys(ob1) } = dictionary
```

Comment: Its not clear what you're trying to do. what output are you expecting?

Comment: Trying to dynamically get the values from the dictionary based on the keys ob ob1 and put them in separate variables

Comment: @nonyck Dynamically named variables are never a good idea. Destructuring needs fixed targets.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939289/how-to-destructure-into-dynamically-named-variables-in-es6

Comment: You're welcome, maybe you can reformat your question so we can vote to reopen it. Anyway, I've answered that as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.assign` and `map()`

```js
let ob1 = { key1: 'value', key2: 'value2'}
let dictionary = { key1: 'super value', key2: 'other value' }

let res = Object.assign(...Object.keys(ob1).map(key => ({ [key]: dictionary[key] })));
console.log(res);
```

```json
{
  "key1": "super value",
  "key2": "other value"
}
```