# Destructure an object and create variable with key names Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

```
let data = {"a":1,"b":2};
```

I want to destructure this object to automatically create 2 variable with names equal to key without providing the name.
How can I do that? Can I even do that without specifying the keynames?

```
let {} = data;
```

`console.log(a)` should then give `1`

Is this possible?

The reason I want this is because I have string , str = `runcode -s ${a} `
 I want to get the value of "a" automatically when I run `str`
 Even if I change the str to `runcode -s ${data.a} ` and run `str`, the `data.a` doesn't get replace by `1`. How can I solve this ?

Comment: This is just a bad idea. Suppose the object is dynamically generated, this would mean the variable names are going to be dynamically generated as well.

Comment: No, you can't do that. `with (data) { ... }` is a statement that probably kind of does what you think you want, but shortening code _this_ much hurts readability, as well as performance. Using `with` is only allowed in non-strict-mode for this reason, and "automatic" destructuring is also not possible for this reason.

Comment: The reason I want this is because I have  string , str = "runcode -s ${a}" and I want to get the value of "a" automatically when I run `str`                                       Even if I change the str to "runcode -s ${data.a}" and run `str`, the data.a doesn't get replace by 1. How can I solve this

Comment: @user3439399 by using backticks instead of quotes...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts... it's not working. Hence I thought we need to first create a variable with name "a" and only use it that way. Am I wrong?

Comment: `str = "runcode -s ${data.a}";` --> ``str = `runcode -a {data.a}`;``

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thats what I had with back ticks.

Comment: Not according to your question.

Comment: It took the ticks away as I didn't escape it. The problem is that it doesn't replace if I use data.a

Comment: @user3439399 Variables are only expanded inside template literals, not old style strings. That's why you have to put backticks around the value of `str`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I destructure all properties into the current scope/closure in ES2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31907970/1048572) - no, you cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve but you could do it the "old fashioned" way:

```
let str = "runcode -s " + data.a;
```

or the ES6 way:

```
let str = `runcode -s ${data.a}`;
```

with backticks and ${obj.prop}.

*Edit: This is not answering the posters original question asked in the topic. This is just a suggestion on how to solve the problem. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.*