# access all element in an object using ECMAScript destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

for example i have testObject like so:

```
const testObject = {obj1:1, obj2:2, obj3:3}
```

when i want destruct all elements i had to do like this:

```
const {obj1, obj2, obj3} = testObject
```

is there any way like `const {*} = testObject` to destruct all element is an object?
thanks.

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to explain what problem you're trying to solve by doing this. There may be a better solution than what you're attempting.

Comment: [`with(testObject)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) - please take the red warning on the MDN seriously though.

Comment: Doing so would be akin to a `with` statement. It's better that destructuring requires you to explicitly name all the variables you're declaring, so that your code doesn't seemingly randomly reference variables that aren't declared anywhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907970/how-do-i-destructure-all-properties-into-the-current-scope-closure-in-es2015

Comment: @ericArbour i'm using JSX should i wrap return statement with a "with"?

Comment: I would be wary of any attempt to create a bunch of variables in your scope without explicitly naming them.

Comment: I should probably reformulate my "please take the warning seriously" to "don't do what you want to do" and think about whether this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @ASDFGerte i took that warning in account and my elements in object all have a suffix in their key names ( like _R_keyname )