# Destructure all properties

Tags: typescript

I am using p5.js and was wondering if I could use Typescript to destructure all the the properties in the `p5` object. Currently my code looks something like this:

```
const sketch2 = (p5: P5) => {
  p5.setup = () => {
    const canvas = p5.createCanvas(200, 200);
  };

  p5.draw = () => {
    p5.fill(0);
    p5.ellipse(100, 100, 80, 80);
  };
};
```

I could do destructure every property but that could be quite tedious:

```js
const sketch2 = (p5: P5) => {
  let { setup, createCanvas, draw, fill, ellipse } = p5;

  setup = () => {
    const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200);
  };

  draw = () => {
    fill(0);
    ellipse(100, 100, 80, 80);
  };
};
```

Could I use Typescript to destructure all the properties into the scope without naming them one by one?

Comment: When destructuring an object you have to destructure it into smaller, individually named pieces. Verbosity and destructuring come hand in hand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I destructure all properties into the current scope/closure in ES2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907970/how-do-i-destructure-all-properties-into-the-current-scope-closure-in-es2015)

Comment: Not really, I am wondering if Typescript has anything to deal with this.

Comment: Not an answer, but you could simplify to `const sketch2 = ({ setup, createCanvas, draw, fill, ellipse }: P5) => {`

Comment: By doing `let { setup /* ... */ } = p5; setup = somethingElse;` you'll alter only the value of your own, just declared variable `setup`, *not* the the `setup` property of the `p5` object -this will stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line:

```
Object.entries(p5).forEach(([key, value]) => window[key] = value);
```

See the Example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ggcxqd).

- if you are looking for a scoped variable, I have to say there is no way to achieve that.

Comment: I hope this be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but this would this would not work for Typescript.

Comment: Yes it will.  I provided this typescript project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ggcxqd @sergmister

Comment: Did you see the example? @sergmister

Comment: It could run in Typescript, but it's not adding the type information to the scope, which defeats the purpose of using Typescript. It's also adding the entries to the window object, not as variables to the local scope as destructing assignment would.

Comment: I told that it is impossible to use them as local variables. Just in window object.