# Import all in ES6, but not inside an object

Tags: import, ecmascript-6

Is there anyway not to write this:

```
import {replace_in_mtstr, tot_width, rationalize, eval_expression, ascii_to_latex, latex_to_ascii, getIndicesOf, cleanIndices, change_sign, exponentiate, multiply_grouped_nodes, flip_fraction, add_brackets, are_of_type, any_of_type, have_same_ancestors, have_same_type, have_same_text, have_single_factor, have_same_denom, are_same_terms, get_prev, get_next, get_all_next, has_op, parse_mtstr, parse_poly, prepare} from "./functions";
```

in ES6? These are all the exported functions in a different file. The closes thing I know is `import * as object from 'file';`. However, I want to have the functions available directly, not inside an object. Is this possible in ES6?

Comment: Not possible… See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21564110/1048572) and the questions linked there.

Comment: It's not possible. You can do `import functions from "./functions";` and access all those exported functions from `functions` object.

Comment: Ok then :P. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments indicate, this is not possible.